# parsing .net DateTime in Ruby & JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I am using web service that is written in .NET

so it returned date like this `/Date(1101240000000)/`

How is it possible to parse this date format in ruby & js?

Comment: How does this relate to ruby or asp.net? You want solely js parsing of the given datetime format, don't you?

Comment: I want to parse this date format in ruby & js.

Comment: Is telling the authors of the web service to use a less dumb date time format out of the question? (There are standards for this, surely .NET web services support one of them.) If not, it's probably in [*ticks*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx), but no way to tell for sure without knowing what point in time the number is meant to correspond to.

Comment: You'll also have to find out what timezone the ticks value is in, since it counts from a point in time in local time. (Or UTC, if the service deal with UTC times. .NET time handling is a mess.)

Comment: Actually, scratch that. The number is too small to be in ticks, and too large to be a Unix timestamp. It could be *milliseconds* since Epoch, making it Nov 23d 2004 (ish), but that's just guessing.

Comment: Uhm, Ruby is a server-side language, Javascript is client-side. You shouldn't parse it on both sides, it's a nonsense. So once again, WHERE you want to parse it? In js and send it to the server-side via ajax? Or js acts only as a middle-man and you want to do the parsing using Ruby? Furthermore, how did you get this type of date format, so we don't have to guess?

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell us what that number means. Is it [Unix Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)? If yes:

**Ruby:**
 `Time.at(1240915075)`  ( [Time.at](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000334) )

`DateTime.strptime("1318996912",'%s')` ([DateTime.strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html))

**JS:**

```
var date = new Date(unix_timestamp*1000);
```

Comment: It probably isn't, .NET doesn't even support creating Unix timestamps in the BCL.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem in my own codebase and did a little digging into that date format. It's basically just a UNIX date with a timezone, but the date is expressed in *milliseconds* since the epoch instead of the usual seconds.

My solution in Ruby was to pull the date and timezone out of that date string with a regexp, divide the date's numeric representation by 1000, and then just use strptime:

```
def date_from_asp_net(asp_net_date)
  date_pattern = /\/Date\((-?\d+)(\+\d+)?\)\//
  _, date, timezone = *date_pattern.match(asp_net_date)
  date = (date.to_i / 1000).to_s
  DateTime.strptime(date + timezone, '%s%z')
end
```

You can probably derive a JavaScript solution from that.

Comment: Very long after the fact, but just wanted to say that this was probably the most elegant Ruby solution to this issue that I have seen while scouring SO over the past day.